# How to get the title from an iframe element using selenium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the title from an iframe tag like this:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {  By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

let driver;

async function whenElement(by_identity,timeout=1000){
  try{
  var el = await driver.findElement(by_identity);
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(el),timeout);
  return el;
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(`whenElement,ELEMENT ${by_identity} not found, ERROR=>${err}`);
  }
} 


(async ()=>{
  driver=await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  await driver.get(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo`);
  await driver.getTitle().then(text=>{console.log(text)});

  await driver.switchTo().frame(await whenElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/fieldset/ul/li[5]/div/div[1]/div/div/iframe'),5000))
  await driver.getTitle().then(text=>{console.log(text)});

})();
```

the expected output should be:

> ```
> reCAPTCHA demo
> reCAPTCHA
> ```

but I'm only getting the title of the main page and not the iframe despite switching the frame of the driver like this:

> ```
> reCAPTCHA demo
> reCAPTCHA demo
> ```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong
maybe my understanding of changing the driver frame is wrong? because as far as I know, if you `driver.switchTo().frame()` then the driver only operates within that frame and can't interact with other elements in other frames or main html DOM

can someone please explain what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to switch to frame to get the title. Instead you can use this:

```js
var frameElm = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('.//iframe[1]'));
console.log(frameElm.getAttribute("title"));
```